# shrinking vbulletin ulrs to as small as possible

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, vbulletin

I was trying to play with vbulletin friendly url option at the admin cp to get the urls of the forum to be as small as possible to be remembered to visitors, and couldn't achieve what I'm after.

well, I want simply to make all long urls to be short from this:

> www.myforum.com/en/threads/1220-my-topic-about-moon

to this:

> www.myforum.com/en/thr1220

so basically I want to skip the word **threads** and add **thr** for example to the end of the url+ the thread number without listing the thread title.

Here is the .htaccess code I got from my vbulletin that I believe where the modification starts:

```
RewriteEngine on


# If you are having problems or are using VirtualDocumentRoot, uncomment this line and set it to your vBulletin directory.
# RewriteBase /forum/


# If you are having problems with the rewrite from content/ to content.php, uncomment this line to turn MultiViews off.
# Options -MultiViews


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d


RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]


# Forum
RewriteRule ^threads/.* showthread.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^forums/.* forumdisplay.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^members/.* member.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^blogs/.* blog.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^entries/.* entry.php [QSA]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d


RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

Any idea how this code can be changed or modified to achieve what I'm after.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like vBulletin is handling this stuff internally, threads simply get routed to `showthread.php` without any external manipulation so it's likely if you changed the structure of the URL, `showthread.php` won't work. There may be a way to reconfigure vBulletin to handle the new URI structure

Comment: possibly, but if you looked at the code above you would notice that they convert **showthread.php** to any word replacing that. so I believe there must be a way how to achieve that. I have seen it in some forums though

Comment: ok, look here if you insist on example: http://www.forexmegacashback.com/en/threads/16458-MyfxBook-Forex-Contest-February-2013-FIBO  what happening is that showthreads.php has been converted to threads as well as forumdisplay.php in other part of the forum pages. That means yes it is possible to shorten the url and replace some links with strings only...

Comment: "*possibly, but if you looked at the code above you would notice that they convert showthread.php to any word replacing that.*" Yes, that's exactly what I said. The script is probably getting the important bits, like the thread ID (e.g. 1220) by parsing the `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL']` or `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variables. Which means if you simply send `/en/thr1220` to `showthread.php`, **it may not be able to parse it**.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I just tried and didn't work. I would love to know how this can be changed... Thanks for the useful comments